# Unity Resolve<T>() equals "new T" in simplest case of concrete type T?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, prism

I am new to .Net Unity DI container. In simple Prism WPF sample code, I see:

```
var shell = container.Resolve<Shell>();
```

Where Shell is concrete type, and is not registered in Unity anywhere. Does this mean above statement simply return "new Shell()"?

Answer (score 2):

If 'Shell' has a default public constructor or a non default constructor with constructor parameters which are:

1. Concrete types also (with a default constructor or all constructor parameters are resolvable by the container)
2. Are interfaces which are registered with Unity

Unity is able to build an instance of 'Shell'. This process is known as 'autowiring'.

It is however best practice to register all your dependencies in your container. By all dependencies I mean all types that are:

1. Constructor parameters for other types
2. Are directly resolved from the container using `container.Resolve()`

Failing to do so, will become a mess when your program grows overtime. There will come a time when a former autowired dependency will fail to be build by the container because the component has now a dependency on some other component which can't be resolved, thereby breaking the application at runtime.

A second reason for doing this, is that there are containers out there which are able to [verify your configuration](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#verify-the-container-s-configuration), thereby helping you to spot mistakes or misconfigurations early in the process. If the container is unaware of all components it won't be able to do a full verification.

Verifying your configuration is usefull because one of the downsides of using a DI container is that you miss compile time support, that you would have got when you would use a handcrafted [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) (known as [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/)).

Verifying the configuration does not guarantee a bug free application but it brings somewhat back from having compile time support.

Registering all your types also takes the magic out the DI container which helps you understand how a container works and what to do in somewhat more complex scenarios.

Another reason to register your types is because this gives you control over the lifetime of the component. If you won't register your types with the container, the container does not know which lifetime to use and thereby registers the component using its defaults. But this is where it becomes tricky. Because different containers have different defaults. Most container default to `Transient` (e.g. [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#transient)) while others default to `Singleton` (e.g. [Castle Windsor](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/mvc-tutorial-part-7-lifestyles.md)). This makes switching between DI containers hard and unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks. Shell has default constructor. When you said "best practice to register all your dependencies in your container", do you mean I have to also register instance of Shell, even though it is a concrete type?

Comment: @Sheen If the answer, answered your question, consider to mark it as answered.